# print () is executing commands. is it normal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I used the print function like this, it ran the command instead of encountering any errors.

```
def x(y):
    print(y*2)
print(x(12))
```

can someone keep me informed?

Comment: Why do you expect this to generate errors?  This should print `24` then `None`.  All  Python functions return some value.  If you don't specify a value to return, `None` is returned automatically

Comment: When you pass a function to `print()` it prints whatever that function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return in your function

```
def x(y):
    return(y*2) # important
print(x(12)) # first the function x is called and then the result is printed
```

It can be then also rewritten to:

```
var = x(12) # function returns 24
print(var) # prints out 24
```